# Bash Script for Rar command

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell-script, rar

I need a script to rar my files

usage will be like this

```
r1 archivename fileordirtocompress
```

with following attributes

```
rar a -m0 -v1024000 -r
```

How whould this bash script look like?

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in "$*"
do

rar a -v10000k archive.rar $file

done
```

I found something like that but I wish I could change the archive name

examples:

> r1 MyPhotos Myphotos/  =  MyPhotos.rar (Myphotos/ inside with
>   subfolders)
>
> r1 Nicemusic *.mp3  = Nicemusic.rar (all .mp3 inside)
>
> r1 Familyvideo movie1.avi = Familyvideo (movie1.avi file inside)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the variable `$file` to name the archive as well.

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in "$*"
do

    rar a -m0 -v1024000 -r ${file}.rar $file

done
```

Note that I changed the options to `rar` to what you said you wanted. The `for` loop stores every file it finds in `*` (i.e. every file in the current directory) in the variable `$file`, one by one, as it goes through the loop. You need the `{}` around the name of the variable before `.rar` to make sure bash doesn't think you're trying to find a variable called `$file.rar`.

Comment: It's not working with folders with space

r1 Phot My/ Photo\

giving:

    WARNING: No files

Comment: Try enclosing the `$file` in quotes, like so: `"$file"`